# Trying to write a for loop that alerts each item in this order without writing alert() for each item?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Do the
D
A
N
C
E
1
2
3
4
5
Stick to the
B
E
A
T
Get ready to ignite

So I am trying to write a for loop that alerts each item above in that order without having to write alert() for each of them. I don't know exactly how to approach this but this is what I have for now:

```
var dance = ["Do the", "D", "A", "N", "C" "E", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "Stick to the ", "B", "E", "A", "T", "Get ready to ignite"];
for (var i= 0, i < dance.length; i += 1) {
    alert(dance[i]); 
}
```

But I'm pretty sure my code is wrong. Is there anything I didn't add to my code? What exactly is wrong?

Comment: you think it's wrong.  How is that a question?

Comment: Check your for loop's syntax: `for (var i = 0; i <= dance.length; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are having difficulties running this code, it will not run because there is a comma missing after the "C".

```
var dance = ["Do the", "D", "A", "N", "C" "E", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "Stick to the ", "B", "E", "A", "T", "Get ready to ignite"];
```

should be

```
var dance = ["Do the", "D", "A", "N", "C", "E", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "Stick to the ", "B", "E", "A", "T", "Get ready to ignite"];
```

Comment: It fixes the problem.  Why a comment?

Comment: What about **without having to write alert()** as mentioned in Question!

Comment: I am interpreting it as "my program doesn't work, it doesn't write alert()" as what you mentioned would be too obvious.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous answer and comments, there are syntax errors in your code i.e. missing `,` in array and your for loop had to be like `for (var i = 0; i < dance.length; i++)`

To achieve this, you need to change the `innerText` of the container element and that to be done after some `timeout`

Refer this example:

```js
var oops = document.getElementById('oops');
var dance = ["Do the", "D", "A", "N", "C", "E", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "Stick to the ", "B", "E", "A", "T", "Get ready to ignite"];
for (var i = 0; i < dance.length; i++) {
  setTimeout((function(i) {
    return function() {
      oops.innerText = dance[i];
    }
  })(i), 1000 * i);
}
```

```css
.oops {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 38pt;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  color: #ff2d4b;
  z-index: 999;
  text-shadow: #333333 3px 3px 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="oops" id="oops"></div>
```

> In this example, I am using `IIFE` as first argument of `setTimeout` just to keep the value of `i` in the memory which will be used when the callback of timeout will be executed!